# Understand notation of motion equation in the context of differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, initial-value-problems

I'm working on practice problems to get familiar with differential equations, but can't quite understand the notation of the following problem:

---

The motion equation $\dot v = g - \alpha v |v|$ is given for velocity v with acceleration $g > 0$ and quadratic friction of a sinking body with $\alpha > 0$ and initial value $(0) = v_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

---

Now it is asked to find out for which initial value $v$ will be constant. Since I have zero experience in physics and have just gotten started with differential equations, I'm struggling with the notation. I understand that $\dot v$ probably denotes $y^{\prime}$ and therefore $v$ will be $y$, but what is $g$? I would be very thankful for any clarifications.

Comment: It depends on the context. Normally it's a constant  g, which denotes the acceleration due to gravity.

Comment: and $\dot v=\dfrac{dv}{dt}$ (that's [Newton's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Newton's_notation))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many notations for differentiation:
Leibniz's Notation $\frac {dy}{dx}$. Newton's dot notation $\dot{y}$. Euler's notation $Dy$. And the most common notation is surely Lagrange's notation $y'$. Alle these notations are equivalent. For g it's certainly a constant. And as Tanner wrote in the comment, $\dot v$ stands for $\frac {dv}{dt}$.

Now it is asked to find out for which initial value v will be constant?

When $v$ is constant, its derivative is $\dot v=0$

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the helpful edit. As I have pointed out in my comment to the answer of Mohammed, I'm not sure how to solve for $v$ if g is supposed to be constant, my approach does not feel like it makes sense...

Comment: @psyph why ? What did you get ? h is surely a constant of acceleration

Comment: So is $\sqrt(\frac{g}{\alpha})$ right?

Comment: yeag @psyph looks correct to me.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask you more questions regarding the whole task in this comment or should I open another question?

Comment: YW.   Maybe if it's another subject it's better to post a new quesion. @psyph

Comment: I'd say it's still the same subject, just tell me if, in your opinion, it's off-topic, and I will delete. It is asked, for which initial values the function $v$ is strictly-monotonically increasing/decreasing.

Comment: It's better to ask a new question so you get more attention and answers. i guess now the question has nothing to do with first question where v is contant.

Comment: When a function $f(x) $ is inreasing on an interval $I$ it's derivative $f' (x)\ge 0$ in that interval.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a constant velocity you need $\frac {dv}{dt} =0$

That is $\alpha v|v| = g$

Solve for $v$ to get the initial velocity.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer.